# Time.sleep() zeroes photo resistor readings on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, sensor, python-3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and a photoresistor, LEDs, resistors, breadboard etc. Now, I have observed a strange occurrence. When I run the following code all of the readings from the light sensor are zeroed.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

class LightSensor():
    def __init__(self, min_light):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
        self.min_light = min_light

    def main(self):
        GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN)

        self.reading = 0
        while (GPIO.input(18) == GPIO.LOW):
            self.reading += 1

        print("Light Reading:", self.reading)
        if self.reading > self.min_light:
           GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
           GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)

light_sensor = LightSensor(min_light=600)

while True:
    try:
        light_sensor.main()
        sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I then removed the `sleep(1)` call from the code. This makes the code output readings normally. However, this fix is quite annoying as the readings are rapid. How could I fix this?

Edit:

It is wired in the following way:
[image: setup]

Further explanation can be found at https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-light-sensor/.

Comment: How are these wired?  Your code has several apparent problems, but the fix is less obvious since we have to guess the connections. You (probably) shouldn't be doing the `GPIO.setup` calls each time that you call `main`.  Typically those should be configured once per program.  Secondly, you use pin 18 as both an output and an input, which seems like it cannot be right.

Comment: At a guess a capacitor is being discharged by connecting it to ground and then the GPIO is set as an input.  The time to recharge to 1 is timed by the busy loop and gives an approximation of the light.  Presumably the capacitor is being charged through a light dependent resistor.  If the guess is correct all this should have been in the question.

Comment: I have edited the question. @joan

Comment: Hopefully, the new information in the question will help @Brick

Comment: `observed a strange occurrence` ... what were you expecting? ... you did not say

Comment: there are no readings from the light sensor. your program refers to pins 17 and 18.  you connected to neither of those.  why are you surprised?

Comment: Ya, your code shows the BCM pin numbers are being used. You show your input connected to BCM pin 4

Comment: The question cannot describe what you're doing still, for the reasons stated by others (wrong pin numbers, not enough pins shown connected to match the code). In addition, it would help for you to provide sample output from your program and what you expect to see.  Looks likely that @joan guessed a good part of the answer in that it probably has to do with the time necessary to charge or discharge that capacitor shown.